# Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Tags: java, web-services, ssl, tls1.2, peer

Good day,

The application is hitting `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated` When I call to infobip new web service, url : `api3.infobip.com`

Before this, the application working fine if call to old url : `api2.infobip.com`

Not sure is my application or the web service problem. I do some testing in this website https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html and trying to understand the result.

For `api2.infobip.com`, which is result in https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api2.infobip.com , I found that `Java 6u45` and `Java 7u25` can call web service correctly with `TLS 1.0`.

However, for `api3.infobip.com`, which is result in https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=api3.infobip.com , I found that `Java 6u45` and `Java 7u25` showing `Server closed connection`.

And my application are using Java 6 , May I know this is my application configuration problem? Or this is the web service problem? If yes, what should I report to the web service person ? Tell them that the new web service are not support for Java 6 and Java 7 ?

Kindly advise.

The error log is as follow:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: peer not authenticated
    at retrofit.RetrofitError.networkError(RetrofitError.java:27) ~[retrofit-1.9.0.jar:na]
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:395) ~[retrofit-1.9.0.jar:na]
    at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:240) ~[retrofit-1.9.0.jar:na]
    at infobip.api.client.$Proxy331.execute(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at infobip.api.client.SendSingleTextualSms.execute(SendSingleTextualSms.java:49) ~[infobip-api-java-client-1.1.0.jar:na]
    at com.cv.ibs.infobip.notification.camel.InfoBipWebServiceProcessor.process(InfoBipWebServiceProcessor.java:43) ~[com.cv.ibs.cib.ws.jar:na]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AsyncProcessorTypeConverter$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorTypeConverter.java:43) ~[camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DeadLetterChannel.process(DeadLetterChannel.java:172) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DeadLetterChannel.process(DeadLetterChannel.java:93) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:115) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:89) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:47) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:41) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:66) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:47) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:151) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:136) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:93) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:75) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.request(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:172) [camel-core-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
```

...

```
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:17) ~[na:6.0 build_20140221]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:399) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.updateSecureConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:167) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.layerProtocol(AbstractPoolEntry.java:275) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.layerProtocol(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:138) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.establishRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:704) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:421) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554) ~[com.ibm.ws.prereq.jaxrs.jar:na]
    at retrofit.client.ApacheClient.execute(ApacheClient.java:71) ~[retrofit-1.9.0.jar:na]
    at retrofit.client.ApacheClient.execute(ApacheClient.java:65) ~[retrofit-1.9.0.jar:na]
```